# Ansible shell not running Helm command

Tags: shell, ansible, kubernetes-helm

Is there a way to add the helm repo using ansible? I'm trying to automate it as part of a playbook that bootstraps a cluster, installs helm, and adds the stable repo.

Everything works fine except the add repo bit.

I have this task in my ansible yaml definition

```
- name: Add helm stable repo
  shell: helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
```

But I get the error

```
"changed": true, "cmd": "helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/", "/bin/sh: 1: helm: not found" "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: helm: not found"]
```

Which is weird cause helm is definitely installed. 
I can ssh into the box and run

```
helm version --short
v3.2.0+ge11b7ce
```

And when I run

```
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
```

directly, it works. But not via ansible.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Are you familiar with what the `PATH` environment variable does? Have you compared your login shell's `$PATH` against the `ansible_env.PATH` value?

Comment: FYI, ansible has a [`helm` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/helm_module.html#helm-module)

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by doing

```
- name: Add helm stable repo
  become: yes
  become_user: vagrant
  shell: helm repo add stable {{ helm_stable_repo }}
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  register: "results"

- debug:
    var: results
```

Looks like I just needed to get it to run as the user `vagrant`.

I added `executable: /bin/bash` to force it to use `/bin/bash`
Didn't really need to in the end though.

And the `debug` flag to see the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem using [this](https://app.vagrantup.com/ilionx/boxes/ubuntu2004-minikube/versions/1.1.0-20210902) vagrant box which comes with helm and minikube pre-installed.
Tried a few things but what worked was to use something like this when using the shell provider:

```
/home/vagrant/bin/helm install -f config.yaml consul hashicorp/consul
```

You can use [Ansible helm provider](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/helm_module.html) as Zeitounator
mentioned... Then something like this would work:

```
- name: Deploy Prometheus chart inside monitoring namespace (and create it)
  community.kubernetes.helm:
    name: test
    chart_ref: stable/prometheus
    release_namespace: monitoring
    create_namespace: true
  environment:
    PATH: /home/vagrant/bin:{{ ansible_facts.env.PATH }}
```

Basically had to add /home/vagrant/bin to PATH to make sure it works...